# The jupyter kernel keeps dying while importing custom dataset

Tags: pandas, kernel, jupyter

I'm using vscode and jupyter extension to do some machine learning stuff, but my jupyter kernel is keeping crashed. I am getting the cell output like this:

I was running the code like this:

```py
dfs = []

for filename in tqdm(os.listdir('./data/train')):
    df = pd.read_pickle(f'./data/train/{filename}')
    df = df[df['label'].apply(lambda x : x in class2id.keys())]
    df['label'] = df['label'].apply(lambda x : class2id[x])
    df = df[['global_graph', 'superpixel_label', 'image', 'label']]
    df.columns = ['graph', 'superpixel', 'image', 'label']
    dfs.append(df)

train_df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop = True)
```

The jupyter log regarding the crashing cell is as follows. I've set the jupyter output mode in verbose.

```
debug 07:32:08.607: KernelProcess Exit Exit - undefined 
error 07:32:08.608: Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: undefined, Reason: 
info 07:32:08.608: Dispose Kernel process 4015157.
error 07:32:08.609: Raw kernel process exited code: undefined
debug 07:32:08.609: shutdownSession aca3d483-6cb0-46f6-8b62-2aed9a344b5f, .jvsc74a57bd0c699c477c5c471d47a8de7a9cc4729800768f3401aa4bd1bfce7df4275c2064e./home/work/python.-m#ipykernel_launcher - start
debug 07:32:08.613: Session can be shutdown .jvsc74a57bd0c699c477c5c471d47a8de7a9cc4729800768f3401aa4bd1bfce7df4275c2064e./home/work/python.-m#ipykernel_launcher
debug 07:32:08.626: Disposed Kernel process 4015157.
error 07:32:08.627: Error in waiting for cell to complete [Error: Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
    at t.KernelShellFutureHandler.dispose (/home/work/.vscode-exts/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.10.110-universal/out/extension.node.js:17:427328)
    at /home/work/.vscode-exts/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.10.110-universal/out/extension.node.js:17:446380
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at y._clearKernelState (/home/work/.vscode-exts/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.10.110-universal/out/extension.node.js:17:446365)
    at y.dispose (/home/work/.vscode-exts/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.10.110-universal/out/extension.node.js:17:439847)
    at /home/work/.vscode-exts/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.10.110-universal/out/extension.node.js:2:593313
    at t.swallowExceptions (/home/work/.vscode-exts/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.10.110-universal/out/extension.node.js:7:167240)
    at p.dispose (/home/work/.vscode-exts/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.10.110-universal/out/extension.node.js:2:593291)
    at t.RawSession.dispose (/home/work/.vscode-exts/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.10.110-universal/out/extension.node.js:2:598289)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)]
warn 07:32:08.628: Cell completed with errors {
  message: 'Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done'
}
info 07:32:08.631: Cancel all remaining cells true || Error || undefined
debug 07:32:08.631: Cancel pending cells
debug 07:32:08.635: Cell 18 executed with state Error
debug 07:32:08.636: Cell 19 executed with state Idle
debug 07:32:08.636: Cell 21 executed with state Idle
debug 07:32:08.636: Cell 22 executed with state Idle
debug 07:32:08.636: Cell 23 executed with state Idle
debug 07:32:08.636: Cell 24 executed with state Idle
debug 07:32:08.636: Cell 25 executed with state Idle
debug 07:32:08.636: Cell 26 executed with state Idle
debug 07:32:08.636: Cell 27 executed with state Idle
debug 07:32:08.636: Cell 29 executed with state Idle
debug 07:32:08.636: Cell 30 executed with state Idle
debug 07:32:08.636: Cell 31 executed with state Idle
debug 07:32:08.636: Cell 32 executed with state Idle
debug 07:32:08.636: Cell 33 executed with state Idle
debug 07:32:08.636: Cell 34 executed with state Idle
debug 07:32:08.636: Cell 35 executed with state Idle
debug 07:32:08.636: Cell 37 executed with state Idle
debug 07:32:08.636: Cell 38 executed with state Idle
debug 07:32:08.636: VSCodeNotebookController::handleExecution, Class name = O, completed in 59481ms, has a falsy return value
debug 07:32:08.636: shutdownSession aca3d483-6cb0-46f6-8b62-2aed9a344b5f, .jvsc74a57bd0c699c477c5c471d47a8de7a9cc4729800768f3401aa4bd1bfce7df4275c2064e./home/work/python./home/work/python.-m#ipykernel_launcher - shutdown complete
debug 07:32:08.636: VSCodeNotebookController::handleExecution, Class name = O, completed in 59333ms, has a falsy return value
debug 07:32:08.636: VSCodeNotebookController::handleExecution, Class name = O, completed in 58944ms, has a falsy return value
debug 07:32:08.636: VSCodeNotebookController::handleExecution, Class name = O, completed in 58753ms, has a falsy return value
debug 07:32:08.636: VSCodeNotebookController::handleExecution, Class name = O, completed in 58576ms, has a falsy return value
debug 07:32:08.636: VSCodeNotebookController::handleExecution, Class name = O, completed in 58324ms, has a falsy return value
debug 07:32:08.636: VSCodeNotebookController::handleExecution, Class name = O, completed in 58154ms, has a falsy return value
debug 07:32:08.636: VSCodeNotebookController::handleExecution, Class name = O, completed in 57893ms, has a falsy return value
debug 07:32:08.636: VSCodeNotebookController::handleExecution, Class name = O, completed in 57724ms, has a falsy return value
debug 07:32:08.636: VSCodeNotebookController::handleExecution, Class name = O, completed in 57070ms, has a falsy return value
debug 07:32:08.636: VSCodeNotebookController::handleExecution, Class name = O, completed in 56921ms, has a falsy return value
debug 07:32:08.636: VSCodeNotebookController::handleExecution, Class name = O, completed in 56760ms, has a falsy return value
debug 07:32:08.636: VSCodeNotebookController::handleExecution, Class name = O, completed in 56508ms, has a falsy return value
debug 07:32:08.636: VSCodeNotebookController::handleExecution, Class name = O, completed in 56226ms, has a falsy return value
debug 07:32:08.636: VSCodeNotebookController::handleExecution, Class name = O, completed in 56036ms, has a falsy return value
debug 07:32:08.636: VSCodeNotebookController::handleExecution, Class name = O, completed in 55753ms, has a falsy return value
debug 07:32:08.636: VSCodeNotebookController::handleExecution, Class name = O, completed in 55232ms, has a falsy return value
debug 07:32:08.636: VSCodeNotebookController::handleExecution, Class name = O, completed in 54972ms, has a falsy return value
```

I've checked several issues that might cause the kernel to crash, but I couldn't find any issues. I've checked these:

1. The crash is not caused by memory issue. I've check my memory usage while importing data. I had no problem at all.
2. I've reinstalled all of the python packages I use, as well as ipykernel itself. It did not work either.
3. I've reinstalled jupyter as well. This did not make any solution to me.
4. Since the crash might be related to jupyter extension, so I tried jupyter notebook environment or python environment. Jupyter got crashed as well, and the python execution was killed.